# Using valueChanges for API call

Tags: angular

I have a situation when I need to listen to changes of a date input and for that I use `valueChanges` and subscribe to it. On each change I need to make an API call to backend in order to calculate an additional item.

From my understanding subscribing inside a subscribe is not a good practice, however what would be a better solution for this? Using `(change)` on date input instead?

Example:

```
private foo() {
 this.form.controls['dateInput'].valueChanges.subscribe(date => {
   if(date) {
     this.api.doSomehting().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
     })
  }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```js
private valueChangesSubscription: Subscription;

private foo() {
 this.valueChangesSubscription = this.form.controls['dateInput'].valueChanges.subscribe(date => {
   if(date) {
     this.api.doSomehting().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res)
     })
  }
 })
}

OnDestroy() {
  if (this.valueChangesSubscription) {
    this.valueChangesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The take(1) operator automatically unsubscribes itself after the first result returns.  So you don't have a memory leak.

But you should remember to unsubscribe from your valueChanges observable since that one stays alive.